# link arbitrary libraries when building from command line in XCode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4.3

I know it's a bit weird, but I need to build my XCode project from the command line, and I need to be able to specify which libraries to link to at build time. In an old-fashioned makefile, I'd simply specify the .a's for the libtool command. How do I make this happen in XCode 4.3, using xcodebuild? I'm specifying a workspace and scheme as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `OTHER_LDFLAGS="/path/to/library /path/to/another"` on the xcodebuild commandline. See the [Build Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW105) Reference for all the things you can pass.